# unable to determine the MIME type of a file

Tags: java, macos, mime

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn how to determine the MIME type of a file. I'm using Mac OS. Below is the code I came up with. However, when I run the code, the IDE output error:

```
'/Users/justin/Desktop/Codes Netbean/JavaRandom/xanadu.txt' has an unknown filetype.
```

Why is this happening? The file does exist. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class DeterminingMIMEType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path filename = Paths.get("/Users/justin/Desktop/Codes Netbean/JavaRandom/xanadu.txt");

        try {
            String type = Files.probeContentType(filename);
            if (type == null) {
                System.err.format("'%s' has an" + " unknown filetype.%n", filename);
            } else if (!type.equals("text/plain")) {
                System.err.format("'%s' is not" + " a plain text file.%n", filename);
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for Files reveals that a FileTypeDetector is loaded by ServiceLoader. A wee bit of googling leads to:
http://blog.byjean.eu/java/2013/08/22/making-jdk7-nio-filetypedetection-work-on-mac-osx.html
which says that this is a problem with the default FileTypeDetector provided by the Oracle Java7 jvm for Mac OS.
The link also has a way of providing your own FileTypeDetector, though upgrading to Java 8 (maybe?) also will fix the problem.